# import data from a csv file and insert said data to oracle database using bash script

Tags: bash, oracle, csv

I would like to know if there is a possible way besides using sql loader to import data from a csv file and insert said data into oracle database using bash script?

Sql loader was attempted but I want to avoid installing utilities on the linux server.

Comment: "I want to avoid installing utilities" - even something standalone like [instant client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html)? If the CSV file is, or can be, in a directory Oracle can see you could load it as [an external table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-97FC9DFF-A6CF-46CD-9F6F-D88A37C0E79C) and stage from that. But you still need a client to connect to the DB...

Comment: I think, worths to install SQL loader as being the best option which is the fastest method, especially by using direct option. Another nice option might be using python.

Comment: Check out csv2db https://stackoverflow.com/a/69676286/995018 Perhaps the oracledb library works in 'thin mode' and no oracle instantclient is needed.

Comment: If not sqlloader, you could read the csv and built SQL to insert the data.  But you need a client to connect to the db anyway.